# Planning architecture with Timed webhook

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-core, webhooks

### Background

I have a website that written in C# + ASP.NET core (v2.2) and expose this API:

```
POST /api/account/signup
POST /api/account/send-greeting
```

My business strategy is to send the user a greeting (`POST /api/account/send-greeting`) exactly 15 minutes after registration.

### The Problem

So, I need somehow to get register to this new event. I though about 2 options:

1. Run a background task every 1 minute that query the db for new users
   who eglible to get this email.
2. Use distributed queues. Like Azure Storage Queues. With this queue, you can enqueue a message with visibilty timeout. So you can define that you sending now the message to the queue but it will be appear there only after 15 minutes. Then you'll have to deploy a background service who will wait for new active messages on the queue and will execute them.

Those two solution have signification downsides:

1. Solution #1 is the naive solution. It's consume a lot of db resources since it should be running every 1 minute and query all the registered users on the table. This is not efficient since in most part of the day I don't have new registered users.
2. Solution #2 is too cumbersome. You need to use queues and deploy a background service in order to get this done. Sound to me like too much work.

This task is sound for me like something obvious. Better solution, that I'm not sure that exist, can be: 
An external service that you send him message like

```
POST /api/register-to-timed-callback?when=15m&target-url=http://example.com/api/account/send-greeting
```

### The Question

I missed something? How you can solve this on the most easy and efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a queued background service based on `IHostedService`. You then add an item to the queue when the user registers and process that queue via the background service. As you pull items off the queue, you check whether or not it's ready to be sent, based on the time. If so, you hit your `send-greeting` endpoint, otherwise, you requeue the item. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#queued-background-tasks) provide a sample of such a service.

The queue:

```
public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem);

    Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> _workItems = 
        new ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>();
    private SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(
        Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
        _signal.Release();
    }

    public async Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        _workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);

        return workItem;
    }
}
```

And the hosted service:

```
public class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public QueuedHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        TaskQueue = taskQueue;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<QueuedHostedService>();
    }

    public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is starting.");

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

            try
            {
                await workItem(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, 
                   $"Error occurred executing {nameof(workItem)}.");
            }
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is stopping.");
    }
}
```

That code is just straight from the documentation. It mostly supports your use case, but requires a couple of tweaks to get you all the way there. First, since there's a time component (i.e. you only want to process the item in the queue if it's 15 minutes old), you'll want to make the type param of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` something you can encode both a datetime and a func into. That could be a `ValueTuple` or an actual object create specifically for this purpose: it's up to you. For example:

```
ConcurrentQueue<(DateTimeOffset added, Func<CancellationToken, Task> task)>
```

Then, you'll need to modify the dequeue logic to re-queue it if enough time has not passed:

```
public async Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
    _workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);
    if (DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15) < workItem.added)
    {
        _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
        return ct => ct.IsCancellationRequested ? Task.FromCanceled(ct) : Task.CompletedTask;;
    }
    return workItem;
}
```

The return there when it's not yet time is basically just a dummy lambda to satisfy the constraint. You could potentially return something like null instead, but then you'd also need to modify the `ExecuteAsync` method of the background service to add a null check before processing the function.

It's also worth noting that the sample code is designed to be generic and allow you to queue *anything* to be processed. As a result, because of the timing-specific changes that are required, you should use more specific naming: `ITimedBackgroundTaskQueue`, `TimedBackgroundTaskQueue`, and `TimedQueuedHostedService`, for example. This is especially true in light of the fact that the sample interfaces/classes from the docs will actually be integrated in ASP.NET Core 3.0.